# Websocket: How to encode a text to send to a client, in C

Tags: php, c, websocket

I'm trying to develop a function for encode a text in a correct format of websocket data send. this is a function in PHP but I can't translate this in C language.

```
private function encode($text) {
// 0x1 text frame (FIN + opcode)
$b1 = 0x80 | (0x1 & 0x0f);
$length = strlen($text);

if($length <= 125)
    $header = pack('CC', $b1, $length);
elseif($length > 125 && $length < 65536)
    $header = pack('CCS', $b1, 126, $length);
elseif($length >= 65536)
    $header = pack('CCN', $b1, 127, $length);

return $header.$text;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's less need for bureaucracy, so it's much simpler to implement. Normally you expect the caller to provide the output buffer and the text size, so let's do that.

Also, be extra careful with the endianness, your second use of `pack` in that PHP code should be with `'CCn'` instead of `'CCS'`.

Example implementation:

```
static char *hdr_fill(char *buf, unsigned int hlen, size_t plen)
{
    *buf++ = 0x81; /* b1 */

    switch (hlen) {
    case 6:
        *buf++ = 127;
        break;
    case 4:
        *buf++ = 126;
    }

    /* Store length in big endian order */
    switch (hlen) {
    case 6:
        *buf++ = plen >> 24;
        *buf++ = plen >> 16;
    case 4:
        *buf++ = plen >> 8;
    case 2:
        *buf++ = plen;
    }
    return buf;
}

size_t encode(char *buf, size_t bufsize, const char *text, size_t len)
{
    const unsigned int hdrlen = len > 65535 ? 6 : (len > 255 ? 4 : 2);
    if (bufsize < hdrlen + len)
        return 0;
    buf = hdr_fill(buf, hdrlen, len);
    memcpy(buf, text, len);
    return hdrlen + len;
}
```

For convenience it returns the result's size. You will need at least `<stddef.h>` (unless you replace `size_t`) and `<string.h>`.

However, you may want to use a scatter-gather approach instead, as it avoids the copying. In that case you just need to build the header and adjust it's vector. Also, IMO it's more elegant:

```
int setup_header(struct iovec *v, int n)
{
    /* We expect a valid buffer in v[0], and the payload in v[1+] */
    if (n < 2 || v[0]->iov_len < 6)
        return -1;

    size_t len = v[1]->iov_len;
    for (int i = 2; i < n; i++)
        len += v[n]->iov_len;

    const unsigned int hdrlen = len > 65535 ? 6 : (len > 255 ? 4 : 2);
    v[0]->iov_len = hdrlen;
    hdr_fill(v[0]->iov_base, hdrlen, len);
    return 0;
}
```

In this case the return value is zero if successful. For this one you need `<sys/uio.h>` or equivalent.